# Trouble parsing nested json and changing response structure

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am having trouble parsing a json and changing the response structure a little bit. Below is the json i am trying to parse -

```
{
  "subRecords": [
    {
      "row": [
        {
          "practice": [
            {
              "addressId": "123",
              "name":"JON"
     
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "Key": "123456-ABC"
    }
  ]
}
```

my expected output is this without `row`  -

```
{
  "subRecords": [
    {
      "practice": [
        {
          "addressId": "123",
          "name": "JON"
        }
      ],
      "Key": "123456-ABC"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my pojo -

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Test{
     private Map<String,Object>Key;
    
    private List<Map<String,Object>>practice;
    
        private List<Map<String, Object>> subRecords;
    
    
        public List<Map<String, Object>> getSubRecords() {
            return subRecords;
        }
    
        public void setSubRecords(List<Map<String, Object>> row) {
    
           this.practice= (List<Map<String, Object>>) row.get(0).get("practice");
        }
}
```

but i keep on getting parsing error as below-

```
 "errors": {
        "status": "500",
        "title": "Internal Server Error",
        "detail": "N/A\n at [Source: (String)\
```

I am not sure if i am accessing the json correctly i would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please add the parsing error and the code which is doing the parsing and the complete POJO to your question.

Comment: @tgdavies i have tried editing my pojo for better understanding. unfortunately i cannot paste the actual json mentioned in error here but is similar structure to what i have above

Comment: Write a small program which just parses a static string of JSON, into a POJO which is the same as your real POJO, and produces the same error. Just change the names as necessary for privacy.

Comment: Your POJO `Test` seems to be nothing like your JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To parse the 1st JSON to Java object you will need the following data model:

```java
public class Original {
    private List<OriginalSubRecords> subRecords;
}

public class OriginalSubRecords {
    private OriginalSubRecordsRow row;
    private String Key;
}

public class OriginalSubRecordsRow {
    private List<OriginalSubRecordsRowPractice> practice;
}

public class OriginalSubRecordsRowPractice {
    private String addressId;
    private String name;
}
```

Then you need to map `Original` to `Restructured` object with the following data model:

```java
public class Restructured {
    private List<RestructuredSubRecords> subRecords;
}

public class RestructuredSubRecords {
    private List<RestructuredSubRecordsPractice> practice;
    private String Key;
}

public class RestructuredSubRecordsPractice {
    private String addressId;
    private String name;
}
```

Mapping them is quite straightforward with the only detail being that you seem to be only interested in the first `practice` in `row`.